# How to perform CTRL+A in IE11/Safari 8 using webdriver in rich text editor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable automate keyboard actions using webdriver. I tried below ones:

1.

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".notebook-rte-prompt.active .rte-editbox")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

2.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".notebook-rte-prompt.active .rte-editbox")).click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0061')).perform();
```

3.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".notebook-rte-prompt.active .rte-editbox")).click();
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Rich Text editor code is as below.

```
<div class="rte-editbox" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"
    autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 62px;">Editor </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to click on the editbox first, like:

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".notebook-rte-prompt.active .rte-editbox"));
element.click();
element.sendKeys(selectAll);
```

Comment: I tried this too, even this doesn't work.. 

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".notebook-rte-prompt.active .rte-editbox")).click();
  noteBookEditor.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");

Comment: I am getting this error..
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot set the selection end (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds

Comment: I guess many others have the same issue as you do: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4467

Comment: I have seen this link, it is mentioned about iFrame there, but in my case it is "div", if you see my rte html code above.

Comment: Please check if this is your issue too: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/8555